# ext4 SD card formatted on Linux, and will not show on OSX

Tags: linux, macos, partitioning, debian, sd-card

I formatted an SD Card as ext4 on my Debian machine. Before I formatted I deleted all partions, created a single partion, and write the changes.

I was able to mount the SD card on my Debian box and it worked fine. I created a directory and unmounted.

When I tried to use the card on my iMac (El Capitan) the SD card wouldn't appear in Finder or Disk Utility.

I downloaded FuseForOSX and installed. And still it's not showing the SD Card in Finder. If I move the SD card over to my Debian machine it will mount just fine.

Any ideas what's going wrong?

Comment: Have you seen [How can I mount an ext4 file system on OS X?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/29842/how-can-i-mount-an-ext4-file-system-on-os-x)

Comment: Ext4fs is a Linux-native filesystem. There are drivers for it in OS X, but I have no experience with them. Generally speaking, for cross-platform file sharing, FAT remains the best option, although it's got its problems (most notably file-size limits that may be a factor for system backup files, MPEG files, and other big files). If FAT's limitations are an issue, I'd suggest using a *non-journaled* HFS+, since Linux provides HFS+ support natively. (A journal will prevent a read/write mount using default options, though.)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it you already deleted the ext4 filesystem from the card so that should not be a issue.

I would try pluging in the card then in terminal running

```
diskutil -list
```

If you can see it with diskutil in terminal then you can repartition it using that utility. I've run into this sort of situation where the GUI disk utility for some reason unknown cant parse the drive. Usually deleting the whole partition map and relaying it out as GUID or MBR fixed it for me.